# Binomial probability on ports

Tags: probability, statistics

This problem appears very simple, but I am almost positive that it should not be so simple.

> 10 ports. P1,P2,P3...P10 are connected to a computing device which polls
>   them in order to check which is ready. 3 ports out of 10 are ready when
>   we start the cycle. What is the probability that P1,P2 is not ready,
>   and P3 is ready?

N,N,R,X,X,X,X,X,X,X

=0.5 x 0.5 x 0.5 x 1 x1 x 1 x 1 x 1 x 1 x 1
=0.125

Am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not taking into consideration the fact that 3 ports are ready and 7 ports aren't ready, which means you have only $\binom{10}{3}$ permutations instead of $2^{10}$ permutations.

I believe it is called *Dependent Probability* (not sure about the English terminology for that).

In any case, you should ask yourself, out of **all** combinations of 3 ones and 7 zeros, how many start with `001`. And since the remaining 7 digits consist of 2 ones and 5 zeros, the number of permutations that start with `001` is $\binom{7}{2}$.

**Bottom line:**

$\binom{7}{2}=\frac{7!}{2!5!}=21$

$\binom{10}{3}=\frac{10!}{3!7!}=120$

So the overall probability is $\frac{21}{120}=0.175$

Comment: I noticed a terrible mistake I made, its "3 ports out of 10 are ready".

Comment: Sorry, about the confusion.

Answer (score 1):

We will assume that all combinations of three ports are equally likely to be the ones that are ready. The probability that Port 1 is not ready is $\frac{7}{10}$. Given that Port 1 is not ready, the probability that Port 2 is not ready is $\frac{6}{9}$, Given that 1 and 2 are not ready, the probability Port 3 is  ready is $\frac{3}{8}$. Multiply.

Comment: I noticed a terrible mistake I made, its "3 ports out of 10 are ready"

Comment: No problem, it just means minor changes to the numbers.